# Child refreshing self instead of parent after form submission Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, parent-child

I have a popup that has a form. When the form is then submitted to another page (target of form is not self). When I then try to refresh the parent of the pop-up after processing the form, the page itself is refreshed instead of the the parent page. Tried both of the following and they both refreshed the child instead of the parent

```
window.parent.location.reload()
opener_reload()
```

Thanks and sorry if this has already been addressed, I did look at quite a few posts and couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure you target the top-most window, try using `window.top`.

`window.top.location.reload();`